# What do these files mean and how should I replace?

Tags: ls, vagrant

In order to get into Symphony framework I had to install Virtual Box (VB) and Vagrant and SSH into the Ubuntu system I created with the default values of Puphpet. In order for my application to work correctly and remove the annoying '500 internal server error' from my pages, I need to replace a configuration file. It turns out this configuration file is cyan colored and has the '@' symbol behind it. How should I replace it with a custom config file and also make the custom config file look like the original one (from green to cyan aswell)? Do I need to read up somewhere what the cyan color means and/or what the @ symbol means in Ubuntu?

At least what I know about that cyan color means it's something that's called symbolic link.

An image displaying what my folder looks like now:

[image: Ubuntu folder]

**Edit:** More information about the file [here](http://pastebin.com/37jm6B2m).
Do I need to change permission of file to make the second config file match the third one in [this example](http://pastebin.com/P6wMEcEk) of commands (I suppose using chmod)?

Comment: Not sure what cyan means (this can also vary on different configurations), but there's an easy way to find out: use `ls -l` to get a verbose list of files in the current folder. You could also use `stat FILENAME`. Would you please add their outputs to your question ([edit] it and paste the output as plain text, not as screenshot). Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander Will this help?

Comment: I guess I should just move the green file over to the one file that is being refered to?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the `@` after a filename marks it as a symlink.

Specifically, under PuPHPet, everything inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is a symlink to a file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.